# Angularjs data table dissappearing while rendering multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-datatables

I am using angular data table where i am generating table every time user selects an option.For the first input the data table render successfully but after that when user select onther option the data table disappear from the view.The problem can be solved if i place the data table options `vm.dtOptions` and  `vm.dtColumnDefs`  outside the function.But i need to solve the issue keeping the options inside the function as my `$scope.ln` is dynamically generated inside the function and i need this value to limit the loop.So how can i achieve my goal so that instead of disappearing  multiple table can be showed based on user input?

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',['datatables']);
            app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope,DTOptionsBuilder,DTColumnBuilder,DTColumnDefBuilder) {
        
        $scope.department = [
                {value : "1", name : "sales"},
                {value : "2", name : "admin"},
                {value : "3", name : "other"}
            ];
        
        $scope.dep=$scope.selected_dep;
        
        $scope.depshow=function(){
        $scope.dep=$scope.selected_dep;
        if($scope.dep==1)
        {
                $scope.list = [
                    {"eid":"10","dyn1":"dval1","dyn2":"dval2","dyn3":"dval3","sales":"20"},
                   
                    {"eid":"20","dyn1":"dval1","dyn2":"dval2","dyn3":"dval3","sales":"20"},
                    {"eid":"30","dyn1":"dval1","dyn2":"dval2","dyn3":"dval3","sales":"20"}
                ];
              }  
                else if($scope.dep==2)
                {
                $scope.list = [
                    {"eid":"40","dyn1":"dval1","dyn2":"dval2","dyn3":"dval3","sales":"20"},
                   
                    {"eid":"50","dyn1":"dval1","dyn2":"dval2","dyn3":"dval3","sales":"20"},
                    {"eid":"60","dyn1":"dval1","dyn2":"dval2","dyn3":"dval3","sales":"20"}
                ];
                }
         if($scope.dep==3)       {
                $scope.list = [
                    {"eid":"70","dyn1":"dval1","dyn2":"dval2","dyn3":"dval3","sales":"20"},
                   
                    {"eid":"80","dyn1":"dval1","dyn2":"dval2","dyn3":"dval3","sales":"20"},
                    {"eid":"0","dyn1":"dval1","dyn2":"dval2","dyn3":"dval3","sales":"20"}
                ];
        }
        
        $scope.vm = {};
        
            $scope.vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
                  .withOption('order', [0, 'asc']);
        
            $scope.ln=4;
               $scope.vm.dtColumnDefs = [
            ];
            for(var i=1;i<$scope.ln;i++){
        
        $scope.vm.dtColumnDefs.push(DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(i).notSortable()); 
          }
        }
                
            });
```

```html
<html>
        <head>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://phpflow.com/demo/angular_datatable_demo/angular-datatables.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://phpflow.com/demo/angular_datatable_demo/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://phpflow.com/demo/angular_datatable_demo/datatables.bootstrap.css"> 
        </head>
        <div class="container">
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
Select    <select ng-model="selected_dep" ng-change="depshow()" ng-options="item.value as item.name for item in department">

<option value="">select a department</option>   
 </select>
    {{selected_dep}}
        <table  class="table table-striped table-bordered" dt-options="vm.dtOptions" dt-column-defs="vm.dtColumnDefs" datatable="ng">
            <thead>
              <tr>
          <th>Employee ID</th>
         <th>dynamic clm1</th>
         <th>dynamic clm2</th>
         <th>dynamic clm3</th>
          <th>sales</th>

        </thead>
            <tbody>
          
           <tr ng-repeat="data in list">
              <td> {{ data.eid }} </td>
              <td> {{ data.dyn1 }} </td>
              <td> {{ data.dyn2 }} </td>
              <td> {{ data.dyn3 }} </td>
              
              <td> {{ data.sales }} </td>
              </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: If you run the code snippet an error is generated from the first time

Comment: i am getting no error there is a  select option and you have to  select an option to  get the table

Comment: Sorry, I give up. I read through the documentation, but still couldn't figure it out. Good luck to you.

Comment: I fixed your example though so it runs on here. Hopefully someone else will be intrigued and troubleshoot it some more for you.

Comment: ok i am excepting the ans and will be happy if you can show some light on the issue posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44775899/disable-column-sorting-not-working-in-angularjs-datatable

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that you dont have brackets on the

```
else if($scope.dep==2)
```

Comment: thanks for detecting the mistake but that was not the reason of my problem........