# Disable column sorting not working for multiple angularjs datatables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

I am working with multiple angularjs data tables and generating a new table every time user selects an option from the drop down list.Based on the user's selection i make an $http request to fetch new data from the database .For every table i have different dtColumnDefs which is set dynamically since my table column headers are dynamic except 1st two and last columns.My intention is to disable sorting for these dynamic column headers.I am able to find out total number of dynamic columns then run a loop to dynamically disable sorting on those columns.Though the data table renders successfully for every user input but expected columns sorting options are not getting disabled. 
Check the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4Js7ZGQAbJMYQVX1NchN?p=preview) for demo.

**UPDATE**

This is a demo table to understand how to proceed but my original table is little bit complex where i am showing some database rows as column headers and there is also some filtering such as unique ,i am also using index value to count the serial so i could not accept `davidkonrad`'s answer as i don't want to define columns from controller.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['datatables']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder, DTColumnDefBuilder) {

    $scope.department = [{
            value: "1",
            name: "sales"
        },
        {
            value: "2",
            name: "admin"
        },
        {
            value: "3",
            name: "other"
        }
    ];

    $scope.dep = $scope.selected_dep;
    $scope.i = 0;
    $scope.depshow = function() {
        $scope.i += 1;
        var x = 'v' + $scope.i;
        $scope.m = 'v' + $scope.i;
        $scope.dep = $scope.selected_dep;
        if ($scope.dep == 1) {
            $scope.list = [{
                    "eid": "10",
                    "dyn1": "dval1",
                    "dyn2": "dval2",
                    "dyn3": "dval3",
                    "sales": "20"
                },

                {
                    "eid": "20",
                    "dyn1": "dval1",
                    "dyn2": "dval2",
                    "dyn3": "dval3",
                    "sales": "20"
                },
                {
                    "eid": "30",
                    "dyn1": "dval1",
                    "dyn2": "dval2",
                    "dyn3": "dval3",
                    "sales": "20"
                }
            ];
        } else if ($scope.dep == 2) {
            $scope.list = [{
                    "eid": "40",
                    "dyn1": "dval1",
                    "dyn2": "dval2",
                    "dyn3": "dval3",
                    "sales": "20"
                },

                {
                    "eid": "50",
                    "dyn1": "dval1",
                    "dyn2": "dval2",
                    "dyn3": "dval3",
                    "sales": "20"
                },
                {
                    "eid": "60",
                    "dyn1": "dval1",
                    "dyn2": "dval2",
                    "dyn3": "dval3",
                    "sales": "20"
                }
            ];
        }
        if ($scope.dep == 3) {
            $scope.list = [{
                    "eid": "70",
                    "dyn1": "dval1",
                    "dyn2": "dval2",
                    "dyn3": "dval3",
                    "sales": "20"
                },

                {
                    "eid": "80",
                    "dyn1": "dval1",
                    "dyn2": "dval2",
                    "dyn3": "dval3",
                    "sales": "20"
                },
                {
                    "eid": "0",
                    "dyn1": "dval1",
                    "dyn2": "dval2",
                    "dyn3": "dval3",
                    "sales": "20"
                }
            ];
        }

        $scope.x = {};

        $scope.x.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
            .withOption('order', [0, 'asc']);

        $scope.ln = 4;
        $scope.x.dtColumnDefs = [];
        for (var i = 1; i < $scope.ln; i++) {

            $scope.x.dtColumnDefs.push(DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef(i).notSortable());
        }
    }

});
```

```html
    <html>
            <head>
              <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
              <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
              <script src="http://phpflow.com/demo/angular_datatable_demo/angular-datatables.min.js"></script>
              <script src="http://phpflow.com/demo/angular_datatable_demo/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://phpflow.com/demo/angular_datatable_demo/datatables.bootstrap.css"> 
            </head>
            <div class="container">
            <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    Select    <select ng-model="selected_dep" ng-change="depshow()" ng-options="item.value as item.name for item in department">

    <option value="">select a department</option>   
     </select>
        
            <table  class="table table-striped table-bordered" datatable="ng" dt-options="m.dtOptions" dt-column-defs="m.dtColumnDefs" >
                <thead>
                  <tr>
               <th>sr</th>

               <th>Employee ID</th>
               <th>dynamic clm1</th>
                  <th>dynamic clm2</th>
               <th>dynamic clm3</th>
              <th>sales</th>

            </thead>
                <tbody>
              
               <tr ng-repeat="data in list">
                   <td> {{$index+1}} </td>
                                     
                  <td> {{ data.eid }} </td>
                  <td> {{ data.dyn1 }} </td>
                  <td> {{ data.dyn2 }} </td>
                  <td> {{ data.dyn3 }} </td>
                  
                  <td> {{ data.sales }} </td>
                  </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31027497/in-angular-js-how-to-disable-column-sort-feature-for-selected-columns

Comment: Have deleted my useless answer. As mentioned the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521000/how-to-call-the-destroy-function-of-angular-datatables/34288205?noredirect=1#comment76564487_34288205) "thread" I think you are on the track. You must remove the bindings, i.e destroy the dataTable before you reinitialise.

Comment: @davidkonrad still unable to figure this out. check  http://plnkr.co/edit/4Js7ZGQAbJMYQVX1NchN?p=preview

Comment: @query, have undeleted and updated the answer. with a forked plnkr.

Answer (score 1):

OK. Dont know where to start, but you a had broad range of errors in your code (no offense).

- Never declared `x`
- Never actually used `x`
- Never actually used `dtColumnDefs`

And more...After some debugging the overall setup did work. However, your biggest problem was the mix of `ng-repeat` combined with the datatable directive combined with redeclaring the same properties over and over. It was easy to fix the code, but not easy to overcome this extreme race condition. Spent an hour trying to work it out, but it is not possible without a lot of `$compile`'s, `$apply`'s and `$timeout`'s.

It really do not have to be so complicated. As I understand you had two issues 1) `notSortable` did not work 2) you could have different columns (properties) for different lists. Simply let dataTables render the data, and declare `dtColumns` dynamically each time a new list is selected :

```
var columns = [];
for (var prop in $scope.list[0] ) {
  columns.push({ data: prop })
}
$scope.x.dtColumns = columns;
```

Set `$scope.list` as data source :

```
$scope.x.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
   .withOption('data', $scope.list)
```

render the "dataTables way" :

```
<table datatable=""  ....></table>
```

forked plnkr -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/afqKW5uKW7Skfnm62zfq?p=preview**

Comment: no my intention was not to disable sorting for all the columns rather  i want to disable only for column  #1, #2 and #3 for all the tables

Comment: What version of angular datatables are you using? I have the feeling you are using an older version, go for the latest 0.6.2. There is [**no reason for your notSortable not is working**](http://plnkr.co/edit/x8uufPuTGrqxekeL5sL4?p=preview) ...If there is an error, it is not included in your code above.

Comment: tested my code with version  0.6.2 but no error and no luck,I think the problem is not version related.However,i forgot to mention that my code works in the expected way if i use a single table as you used in the plunger but if  there is multiple table i mean multiple call to the function depshow() then this no more works.

Comment: my columns are dynamic except colmun #0 so i have no other choice then using a loop!

Comment: one posted here a demo table to understand how to proceed but my original table is little bit complex where i am showing some database rows as column and there is also some filtering such as unique ,i am also using index value to count the serial so it will be very much helpful for me if your update the plunker keeping the tr tag of the view intact.i mean i don't want to define columns in the controller i want to handle it from the view as my posted plunker.is it possible to achieve ?

Comment: check my updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4Js7ZGQAbJMYQVX1NchN?p=preview) where i tried to build it allowing ng-repeat but no luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try using square brackets inside the `dtColumnDefs`push like

```
$scope.x.dtColumnDefs.push(DTColumnDefBuilder.newColumnDef([i]).notSortable());
```